# Android Manifest is not giving Google Maps the API key

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-manifest

I keep getting this error:

*API key not found.  Check that < meta-data android:name=" com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value=" your API key" /> is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml*

When my maps activity tries to inflate the activity's fragment.

***Has anyone ever experienced this issue?***

In my strings file I have:

```
<string name="google_api_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">an api key that i got from google here</string>
```

I have tried

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="@string/google_api_key"/>
```

and typing the key directly into the field:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="an api key that i got from google here"/>
```

I have also tried:

1. cleaning the cache
2. invalidating caches and restarting
3. ran all my XML files through an XML checker to validate.

**MapActivity.java**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String MAP_COORDS = "com.mycompany.myapp.map_coordinates";
    public static final int MAP_REQUEST_CODE = 453;

    private MyObject myObject;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, MyObject myObject) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, MapActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(MAP_COORDS, myObject);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        return intent;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }
}
```

**MapActivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.MapActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In my Gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_api_key"/>
```

Comment: Where are those `<meta-data>` elements, with respect to the `<application>` element?

Comment: Inside the Application element, right above the Activity declaration.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the API_KEY should be under "application" tag (as follows) and make sure your API_KEY is valid, you should enable "Places API for Android" in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com), not just "Places API".

```
<application
    android:name=...>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_api_key" />

 ...
</application>
```

Also, I can't tell about your MapActivity, but a proper way to start PlacePickerActivity would be something like this:

Kotlin:

```
val builder = PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
```

And Java:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
try {
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
}
catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope one of these help, cheers!